# Bootstrap 3 col-sm-offset-x affects to the col-md-x structure

Tags: class, twitter-bootstrap, grid, offset

I have this code `<div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs">` and bootstrap is making the offset to the col-md-12 too, I'm checking the code and I have no clue why this is happening, I think that this wasn't happening before, but I have go back a lot of steps in the code maybe to the point it was working and nothing.

If I remove the offset it works as suppose...but I don't have the offset on smaller resolutions.

This is the page where you can see the problem: [Test page](http://sociedadrealyantigua.com/movil/)

Is the block where it puts "Especial 52º Aniversario"

Thanks for the help, is driving me nuts

Comment: what line number of your source code do you think is causing the error?

Comment: The one that I put in the message "div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs">" for some reason on large resolution is applying the offset I put on small res.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The offset applies from sm all the way up to max size. To stop it, add in `col-md-offset-0` to prevent the offset applying to larger sizes.

Comment: YES!!! THANKS a lot! I didn't know that, I think that info is not on the bootstrap documentation, but thanks :)

Comment: @user3652601 It is in the docs. From http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid : "Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present."

Comment: Thank you DavidG for your nice, clear and simple answer

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 = Mobile first.

Any styles you apply in the xs 'size' range will be carried through to the larger 'sizes' unless you are using the helper utilities like .visible-sm class

If you want to have a one column offset that is visible during the small range ***only***:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-1 visible-sm"><div>
        <div>
          ...continue your content
        </div>
```